# returning an NA value using a mean function in R

Tags: r, dataframe

```
._883<-quantmod::getSymbols("0883.HK",from="2022-04-21",to="2022-12-22",auto.assign = FALSE)
._600938<-quantmod::getSymbols("600938.SS",from="2022-04-21",to="2022-12-22",auto.assign = FALSE)

x<-cbind(._883[,6],._600938[,6])
x$diff<-x[,2]-x[,1]
na.omit(x)

> mean(x[,3])
[1] NA
> class(x[,3])
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

Hi guys, mind taking a look at the data? I try to get the mean value for the third column but NA is returned.

Thanks to Martin Gal, adding `na.rm=TRUE` does the work perfectly!!

Comment: Perhaps `mean(x[,3], na.rm = TRUE)` solves your problem?

Comment: Rather than leaving as a dangling unanswered, why not employ @martin-gal in your answer and accept yours, as answered questions are typically first searched and considered.

Comment: @Chris, yea I would love to accept his answer, but may I know how do I accept it? I mean Martin posted a comment instead of an answer, is there a way for me to convert his comment to an answer and accept it?

Comment: There are two side to this situation. One is that, should one ?`mean`, one would see that na.rm allows a mean to be derived on non NA values,and essentially enough said. On the other hand, plenty of people don't read ?`mean` or understand it's implications and fall upon this undesired outcome. Those are the two sides. The third consideration is that answered questions are first viewed, so 'answering your own question, based upon reasoned input' guides others to a useful outcome, and hence why I suggest you answer your own question in view of @MartinGal input...IMHO.